# Passing arguments to callback function with in a separte module

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, node-modules

I would create a new separate module with a function that contains a callback that I call in main file.

My program should take **3 args**: first a file directory, then file extention and finally a callback function that should filter a directory by fileextension.

Here's my module.js file

```
var fs = require('fs')

module.exports = function (directory, fileExtension, callbackfun) {
    fs.readdir(directory, callbackfun);
}
```

then in main file I import module then use function.

```
modulejs(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], callbackfun(callbackfn));
var callbackfn = function (err, data, fileExtension) {
    console.log(fileExtension);
    let filtred = data.filter(file => { if (file.indexOf("." + fileExtension) > -1) { console.log(file); } });
};
function callbackfun(callbackfunc1) {
    callbackfunc1(err, data, fileExtension);
}
```

The error that I get actually is

```
ReferenceError: err is not defined
```

**UPDATE**: I have edited my code, I get different error now

**UPDATE2**: I get the solution on internet but does not understand how it works, if anyboby explain it to me step by step it would be nice

```
module.jsconst fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = function (dir, filterStr, callback) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err)
        }

        list = list.filter(function (file) {
            return path.extname(file) === '.' + filterStr
        })

        callback(null, list)
    })
}
```

main.js

```
const filterFn = require('./module.js')
const dir = process.argv[2]
const filterStr = process.argv[3]

filterFn(dir, filterStr, function (err, list) {
    console.log(list);
    if (err) {
        return console.error('There was an error:', err)
    }

    list.forEach(function (file) {
        console.log(file)
    })
})
```

Comment: In the `main` file, `callbackfunc` does not seem to be defined anywhere. The compiler is complaining about that.

Comment: I have updated my code